# How to read an Array variable in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Hello I have the following issue

I have the following function signature :

```
public void doSomething(Object arg);
```

I call this function with the following code segment :

```
doSomething(new Object[] {this,"aString"});
```

In the `doSomething` method implementation how can I read the data (Class Name and String) that I sent when I called it ?

Comment: If you alway pass `Object[]` (as you mentioned in one of your comments) change the method signature to `public void doSomething(Object[] arg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   public static void doSomething(Object arg) {

    if (arg instanceof Object[]) {
        Object[] list = (Object[]) arg;
        for (Object item : list) {
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }

   }
```

This assumes you will always pass an Object[] as argument.

Comment: I always do that, but is there any way to check that I pass an Object[] as argument ?

Comment: if(arg != null && arg.getClass().isArray()) { ... }

Comment: I think Kris answered that for you @SteveSt. Can you mark this as the correct answer if it works for you?

Answer (score 3):

To check whether the passed object is actually an array use

```
if(obj instanceof Object[]) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can introspect the variable passed in using `instanceOf` method

```
arg instanceof Object[]
```

returns boolean.

Or check the class name of the pass variable by calling `arg.getClass()`

```
arg.getClass()
```

return class name as String.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:-

```
public void doSomething(Object arg){
      Object[] arr=(Object[])arg; // cast the arg into Object[] array
      Object obj=arr[0] ;// will return the object
      String s=(String)arr[1] ;// would return string (add a down-cast to string because that string object when added to array converts to the Object type)
      System.out.println(obj+" "+s);
}
```

If you called it in this way

```
doSomething(new Object[] {this,"aString"});
```

Ouput would be something like this:-

```
Class@dce1387 aString
```

Answer (score 1):

use
`arg.getClass().getSimpleName()` to get Class Name
`arg.getClass()` to get fully qualified Class Name
`arg.toString()` to read the data which converts to string.

Assuming you have overidden toString() method

Comment: assuming arg is an object